# How to downgrade Ruby version on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

My Ruby version in Ubuntu machine is `2.1.8` and I need it to downgrade to `2.1.5`. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That's an odd thing to require. Have you tried using [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com)?

Comment: yes,but it gave me the error `RVM:command not found`.

Comment: did you install RVM?

Comment: You have to install it. RVM's really the best thing for managing historical versions of Ruby. If you need a very particular version, like you do, it will get it installed. Ubuntu is more concerned with having a standard version as part of the distribution. If you can install Ruby successfully with RVM, remove your system Ruby to avoid conflict.

Comment: @tadman Great explanation. However, it shouldn't even be necessary to remove the system Ruby, as long as rvm is installed correctly, right?

Comment: @KeithBennett The problem with having two independent Ruby installations is sometimes compiled extensions try and import header files for the system Ruby while building for your specific version. This can cause compile errors.

Comment: I think this is on-topic because Ruby is a tool used by programmers, managing Ruby versions is a very common task for Ruby programmers, and especially since tools like _rvm_ are primarily used by programmers, not end users.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

1)

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

2)

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

3)

```
rvm install 2.1.5
```

Then remove the version of Ruby you'd previously installed.